# Dart: instance variable override

Tags: dart

I'm confusing about the rules of class instance variable override

```
class S0 {
  num a;

  S0(this.a) {
    print("in S0 :$a");
  }
}

class S1 extends S0 {
  num a;

  S1(this.a) : super(a + 1) {
    print("in S1 :$a");
  }
}

main() {
  var b = S1(123);
  print(b.a);
}
```

Above is my code. I expect it prints:

in S0 :124

in S1 :123

123

But the result is:

in S0 :123

in S1 :123

123

Why? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart, [instance variables implicitly create getter and (for non-`final` members) setter functions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#instance-variables).  That is, `S0`'s interface is implicitly:

```dart
class S0 {
  num get a;
  set a(num value);

  S0(num a);
}
```

From this perspective, it should be clearer that when `S0` attempts to access `a`, it uses its getter method, which in this case is overridden by `S1` and thus always returns `S1`'s value.

The construction order is also important.  Constructing an instance of the derived `S1` class would execute:

1. The initialization list from the derived class (`S1`).
2. The initialization list from the base class (`S0`).
3. The constructor body from the base class (`S0`).
4. The constructor body from the derived class (`S1`).

After step 2, the object is considered sufficiently constructed for virtual dispatch to work (i.e., for overrides in the derived class to be called). (This is unlike languages such as C++ where objects are constructed purely from base class to derived and virtual dispatch in constructors is disallowed to prevent invoking methods on unconstructed objects.)

Answer (score 1):

because in the constructor body access to this (and its members) is allowed. so getter and setter is generated before execute constructor.

according to [instance variable](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#instance-variables)

> All instance variables generate an implicit getter method. Non-final instance variables also generate an implicit setter method.

and as described in [Dart Programming Language Specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf) Chapter 10.8.1 Inheritance and Overriding

> Instance variables never override each other. The getters and setters induced by
>   instance variables do.

so when you call this.a in class S0 it's already overrided by child class S1;